# Image Doesn't display in django from sqlite3 databbase

Tags: django, sqlite

I am creating a website that should display several images, but none is displayed.

I have tried several ways to solve it but no changes,
image's URL is saved in sqlite db

**views.py**

```
def add_story(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StoryCreate(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            storyitem = form.save(commit=False)
            storyitem.save()
    else:
        form = StoryCreate()

    return render(request, 'story_form.html', {'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'statics')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**html**

```
      <img name="Story" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" src="{{item.LogoUrl.url}}"/>
```

Comment: When you put the image url (the output of `{{ item.LogoUrl.url }}`) directly in your browsers address bar, are you getting the image? Or what error is it returning?

Comment: the url is saved as well i made alert with, but it didn't work in image src attribute,,,, and when i put another url from pc, it didn't work too, only if i added image address from some sites as google

Comment: url ({{ item.LogoUrl.url}}) didn't work....